# Is GET() method secure to get secure data from server side?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, security

I use `GET()` method to get secret keys and authentication key for aws-sdk, mongojs. AngularJs makes `GET()` request to my `nodejs` `server` which returns my secret keys as json to client side angurajs controller.

**service.js**

```
myApp.factory('Api',['$resource', function($resource){
    return {
MediaCreds: 
            $resource('/key/secret/creds/:id', {
                id: '@id'
            })
}]);
```

**NodeJs**

```
router.get('/key/secret/creds', function(req, res){    
     var Creds = require('../../config/key.js')              
     //console.log(Creds);
     res.json(Creds);
});
```

**index.js**

```
myApp.controller('userVarCtrlr', ['$scope', 'userVar', 'Api', function($scope, userVar, Api){
  $scope.Creds = {};
  Api.MediaCreds.get({},function(data){
         $scope.Creds = data;
         userVar.Creds = data;
         console.log($scope.Creds );
    }); 
   //...
   //Using Creds for atuhenticating to use aws or mongojs..
}]);
```

GET() method is encrypted but is it possible that someone on the clientside makes key visible?

Is this method secure or is there a better way?

Comment: Anything that makes it to the client is visible to whoever controls the client.

Comment: Then how do i update my AWS s3 keys on client side without making it visible?

Answer (score 4):

GET, POST, ... would not make a big difference - all these call are public and it is just a way to format the data, headers, etc...
If you want to secure, your get/post call, you need to use https to encrypt the data. But that would just secure the information, not the call itself. If you want to secure the query, use a protocol like oAuth. oAuth 1.0a without https, oAuth 2.0 with https. Now on the client side and because of the nature of javascript, the client itself can see the information.

Comment: For now I need response data to be encrypted. So using https will encrypt my data and will not be visible untill I print it anywhere(like in frontend or console). Right?

Comment: The encryption provided by HTTPS only involves the network traffic. Once the information is in the browser, it's no longer encrypted and the user of the browser can easily see it.

Comment: But if i dont print it ..just get the data and use it ,  can it still be viewed on client side?

Comment: @Karan, Data being transmitted is generally a form data which is being entered by user. What security you need for that ?

Comment: @Karan if there is some information that an ordinary user of your web interface should not ever see, then don't send that information to the client. Even if your JavaScript code does not explicitly show the information (in a form field or by updating the DOM somehow), the browser user can easily examine what your JavaScript code is doing.